# Weird thing happening on arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, allocation

I have some REALLY wierd thing on my arduino. I made a sketch (I can't post it because I edited it and it has other problems now) and it has a few problems:

It works perfectly when I read using

```
char c;
String cmd = "";
while (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    cmd.concat(c);
}
```

but after I added a new function (I don't even call it) it starts reading only the first 2 characters. If I add one more (the same, I don't call it) the string is empty. What is happening??

Also, I tried

```
char c;
String cmd = "";
while (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(c);
    cmd.concat(c);
}
```

and it prints exacly what I type. Looks like concat is bugged. I read and I discovered it's a memory allocation bug or something but it's really weird. I realized it depends on my code's binary size (if it has about 10.000 bytes it works fine, 11.000 works with only the first 2 chars and more doesn't work at all).

Please help. I know my code isn't wrong and I need help solving this bug.

Best regards,
Mateiaru

Comment: More likely you have invalid code somewhere and you're corrupting your stack or heap.

Answer (score 2):

in arduino, i guess this is what you have:

```
void loop(){
    char c;
    String cmd = "";
    while (Serial.available()) {
        c = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(c);
        cmd.concat(c);
    }
}
```

in that code, while a new character is being sent (and you've read the entire buffer), you have

```
Serial.available() = FALSE
```

so the main loop sets

```
cmd = ""
```

and you lose the previous data. Fix this inicializing `cmd` outside the main loop, and also inicialize `c` outside the loop:

```
char c;
String cmd = "";

void loop(){
    while (Serial.available()) {
        c = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(c);
        cmd.concat(c);
    }
}
```